# Como puedo trazar la ruta dependiendo de los datos introducidos en el origen y destino?

Tags: javascript, html5, json, geojson

Estoy utilizando la API de ruteo del Inegi, y quiero modificar la forma en la que se traza la ruta, en el código original se traza dando click en en algun camino del mapa, pero lo que yo quiero es modificar para que trace la ruta dependiendo de los valores de origen y destino. (Dicha API de ruteo se puede descargar directamente de la página del INEGI)

Adjunto HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto JS del origen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto JS de la función click

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.